# Is there a Project Manager in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get similar functionality to this one?

https://github.com/randy3k/Project-Manager

Even the out-of-the-box project manager workflow from Sublime would be a nice to have.

Right now I'm working with a structure of files that resembles something like:

```
-Workspace
    - Folder1
      - file1
      - file2 

    - Folder2

    - Folder3
      - file1
      - file2
      - file3

    - Folder4
```

We are managing the project in Jira (so, a ticket based kind of workflow if that makes sense).

I switch between tickets often times and I would like to save the "state/session/current workspace" (all the files that I was modifying at that time) for a specific task I was working on, so that I can also switch between the files that were involved for a particular task.

I guess I should note that the files I work on are spread across folders also.

I can easily save a Sublime's project and workspace for each ticket and switch to it, but I would like to do something similar in VSCode.

**Edit**
It's been quite some time since I asked, and I'm marking the *new answer* from @chachan

I also have been using it for a while now, works very well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this one and works cool so far: https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-project-manager

Comment: I have been using this project for a while now , it is amazing

Comment: Just an update, for those who use git as VCS may be better to use this other extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felipecaputo.git-project-manager

Comment: didn't find "Open Project in a new Window" or "New Workspace for Project" features.  these ARE on the ST plugin, but not on the VC extension.

Comment: This is a famous plugin in Atom, however, it seems its feature is incomplete in VsCode, and not powerful like it is in Atom.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no support for this in VS Code, but its a good idea for an extension.

Answer (score 2):

[Git Project Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felipecaputo.git-project-manager) searches a directory (and subdirs) for git repos so you don't have to manage a list.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to responding so forgive me if I am incredibly late. There is a project manager created by Alessandro Fragnani that can be obtained fromt he VCS Marketplace. I just installed and enabled it earlier today. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @Steven-Craig. I just updated my question and marked an earlier answer that pointed to that project :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [vscode-open-project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svetlozarangelov.vscode-open-project)

It is simple and fast.

More listed here:[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=project&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)